# Stolen iPhone has already been wiped; is there any way to get it back?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

I've had a iPhone that's been lost for a couple of months now. It's been stolen and wiped already, so Find My iPhone doesn't work and Lost Mode is still pending (and has been for a good amount of time). Although we'll be getting a new iPhone in a few weeks, but I'd love to get my old iPhone back (that's a solid $500 I'd like to not lose).

Comment: After being wiped, Find My iPhone should still work since the only way to turn it off or remove it is to sign out.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson Aren't there multiple known workarounds for that? Keep in mind Lost Mode is still pending on the device—is it possible it's been completely wiped and sold already?

Comment: The only workaround is to either know your password, or try a dictionary brute attack to crack the password. This isnt common and it its quickly done. The only way they are selling your phone, is if some sap buys it and then realizes once they get past the Hello screen that they need to put the email address and password in. Erasing the device doesnt sign you out.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson Good to know. Is there any hope of finding it at this point? It says it’s offline.

Comment: Nope, its waiting for a wifi or cellular signal.

Comment: The key here is to remember as long as Find My iPhone was on before you lost it (most people leave it on once they set up the iPhone) then it cant be used without logging in and signing out. https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT201472

Comment: After 48 hours call your local authorities with the Serial & or IMEI number of the device. And by all means contact your carrier now so you arent being charged for service on a device you dont have access to.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson Yeah, it’s been a couple months—I doubt we’re gonna get it back st this point. Thanks, though. :)